# updated object's attribute in python class, but not getting reflected

Tags: python, oop

consider my simple class

```
class stud():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.name=a
        self.mark=b
        self.message=self.name + ' ' +str(self.mark)

s1=stud('student1',40)
print s1.message  --->output=student1 40 
s1.name='student2'
print s1.message ----> output =student1 40 , but i expected student2 40
```

My question here is why when I printed the self.message [after modifying the name attribute of the object], it printed the old value? I know **init** method is called only once during object creation and name attribute is set to value 'student1' at that time. But, i am changing it next line and again printing of self.message shouldn't list the new value?

Why is this self.message is not updating the modified value?

Comment: I cannot believe that I found out this fact after 4 month of learning python. :) Good question!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Trace the execution.

```
s1=stud('student1',40)
```

This sets

- `s1.name` to `"student1"`
- `s1.mark` to 40
- `s1.message` to `"student1 40"`

Think of the attribute values as boxes. Each of the three boxes have a value in them. Two of them hold strings. One of them holds a number. They will hold those values until they are explicitly assigned to. In particular *the attribute message has NO IDEA how it got its value*. It has no idea it got its value by concatenating the `name` attribute and the `mark` attribute. All it knows is that the value it has is `"student1 40"`.

```
print s1.message
```

This outputs `student1 40` (no surprise)

```
s1.name='student2'
```

You updated one of the three attributes. But you did not update the others.

```
print s1.message
```

Since you never explicitly changed `s1.message`, this still outputs `student1 40`.

The point is the value of `s1.message` is just a string. There is no invisible computation that automatically updates it whenever the expression that initialized it gets changed. Other languages work that way perhaps, but Python does not.

If you *want* that behavior, then do this:

```
class stud():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.name=a
        self.mark=b

    @property
    def message():
        return self.name + ' ' +str(self.mark)
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because you initialize the `self.message` in the `init`, and when you did `s1.name = student2`, you only changed the `self.name`, while the `self.message` was already initialized.

If you want to get the `self.message`, you want to update its values somehow.

what will work:

```
class stud():
    def __init__(self,a,b):
        self.name=a
        self.mark=b

    def the_message(self):
        self.message = self.name + ' ' + str(self.mark)
        return self.message

s1 = stud('student1',40)
print s1.the_message() 

s1.name='student2'
print s1.the_message()
```

output:

```
student1 40
student2 40
```

Comment: Yes. I noted this. But my question revolves around why self.message is not working in my question [ without using a seperate function as you just provided].

Comment: but i changed self.name rite? so self.message again should dynamically take new self.name value?

Comment: No. That's the whole point. edited my answer. the `init` gets initialized only one time, when you declare your class.

Comment: @syam Python just doesn't work this way. Are you thinking of a different programming language that does? The fact is, practically every mainstream programming language treats variables (and attributes) as boxes in which you put computed values which are NEVER "dynamically reassigned"! That said, Python, like other languages, gives you language mechanisms to give you exactly that appearance. In Python's case, it is `@property`.

Answer (score 2):

When you call the constructor, it initializes `name`, `mark` and `message`.

If you modify `name`, you don’t call the constructor, so the message is not updated.

This statement is not called again:

```
self.message=self.name + ' ' +str(self.mark)
```

To do that, you need a function or a property to calculate the message each time you need it.

```
    def get_message(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + str(self.mark)


s1 = Stud('student1', 40)
print(s1.message)
s1.name = 'student2'
print(s1.get_message())
```

To use a **property**, you need to inherit from `object` (because this functionality is only available with the new style class in Python 2).

You can do that:

```
class Stud(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.name = a
        self.mark = b

    @property
    def message(self):
        return self.name + ' ' + str(self.mark)

s1 = Stud('student1', 40)
print(s1.message)
s1.name = 'student2'
print(s1.message)
```

Note on code style:

- class names should be in CamelCase,
- variable and function names should be in snake_case.

Comment: Thanks!!! but i changed self.name rite? so self.message again should dynamically take new self.name value? as when i print self.message now, it looks for self.name and it is the new name now.?  self.message is created as part of initialization, but self.name is a variable which i changed after that nah?

Answer (score 1):

Because you have only changed the `name` attribute not the `message` so its still printing the same message.

What you need is define your `message` as an `function` rather than an `attribute`. Go ahead and try it.